# Mocking UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, .net, tdd

I have a class that handles password changes and expiration checks for exchange mailboxes.
I check for LastPasswordSet on a UserPrincipal.

Now what about TDD?

I want to check if my class handles the password checks correctly by writing some tests. But I cant get my head around how I could mock the UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, [some username]).

I'm about to write a method that return true/false if the password has been changed the last 90 days. So I would like to mock the UserPrincipal so I can set the LastPasswordSet return value in my tests just to check the logic I'm about to write for the "password needs change notification".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer that with the pithy phrase

### "Don't mock types you don't own"

couldn't find an authoritative blogpost to back that up. [Sample link](http://stevef.truemesh.com/archives/000194.html). Although it seems to be attributed to Joe Walnes.

UserPrincipal if I remember is a .Net framework class related to authentication. Mocking types that are out of your control (can change) can lead to fragile tests.

Instead discover what your design wants from UserPrincipal

- find the role that UserPrincipal fulfills or implements indirectly via TDDing the clients
- Mock that role in your unit tests and test all callers.
- Have "integration tests" to ensure that your real implementation pushes the right buttons on UserPrincipal when invoked.
- Rely on end-to-end / acceptance tests to find bugs that occur when all components are strung together.

Answer (score 13):

I realize this is an old post, but recently I ran into the same issue as the original poster and after reading the answer, I thought I would have to do the same thing.  I don't want someone else to read this post and lose valuable time like I did, so I decided to truly answer this post.

After realizing that there is no easy way to wrap the UserPrincipal functionality nor rely on integration or end-to-end tests like suggested, I remembered there is a way to mock static classes.  With that being said, below is exactly how to do it using [Telerik JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx).

```
private void MockUserPrincipal()
    {
        //Mock principal context
        var context = Mock.Create<PrincipalContext>((action) => action.MockConstructor());

        //Mock user principal
        var user = Mock.Create(() => new UserPrincipal(context));           

        //Mock the properties you need
        Mock.Arrange(() => user.Enabled).Returns(true);
        Mock.Arrange(() => user.UserPrincipalName).Returns("TestUser");
        Mock.Arrange(() => user.LastPasswordSet).Returns(DateTime.Now);

        //Mock any functions you need
        Mock.Arrange(() => user.IsAccountLockedOut()).Returns(false);

        //Setup static UserPrincipal class
        Mock.SetupStatic<UserPrincipal>();

        //Mock the static function you need
        Mock.Arrange(() => UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Arg.IsAny<PrincipalContext>(), Arg.AnyString)).Returns(user);  

        //Now calling UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity with any context and identity will return the mocked UserPrincipal
    }
```

Comment: Within years, I forgot about shims!  Thanks for sharing, sovled my problem!

Answer (score 3):

Old post but there is a working example. Even though you never should test someone else's code you want to test your methods. And your methods might need data from a `UserPrincipal` that is returned from another method. Now say you need to check the `LastPasswordSet` property.

1. Right click on the .dll `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in your unit test projekt. Choose "Add Fakes Assembly".
2. Add this unit test

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public async Task ActiveDirectoryUserFactory_CreateUserAsyncAndWhatYouExpect()
   {
       // Arrange
       using(ShimsContext.Create())
       {
           var userPrincipal = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Fakes.ShimUserPrincipal();
           var baseUserPrincipal = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Fakes.ShimAuthenticablePrincipal(userPrincipal);


           baseUserPrincipal.LastPasswordSetGet = () => DateTime.Now;

           // Mock the returned UserPrincipal to use our userPrincipal, here's for Moq
           _class.Setup(x => x.GetUserAsync("param"))
               .Returns(Task.FromResult<UserPrincipal>(userPrincipal));


           // Act, your method that gets your shimUserPrincipal from _class.GetUserAsync in your _target class (I understood you got the UserPrincipal from external source)
           var user = await _target.YourMethod();

           // Assert
           Assert.IsNull(user);
       }

   }

   // method that does the code you want to test
   public async Task<Object> YourMethod()
   {
       var user = await _class.GetUserAsync("param");
       var lastLogin = user.LastPasswordSet;
       return new Object()
   }
   ```

There are lot of sources out there for Shims so I let it be like this. Hope this helps someone who googles "mock UserPrincipal".

Comment: You need Visual Studio Enterprise edition to enable the fake assemblies as stated in the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes

Answer (score 1):

The UserPrincipal class is not really TDD friendly, I'm afraid.
What about wrapping the functionality you need in a class of yours and mock that instead?

Comment: Yes, I've thought about that and I probably end up with a UserPrincipalWrapperHelperThingy :-)